# Python: Generating Voronoi tesselation with custom metric

Tags: python, geo, voronoi

I'm interested in generating the voronoi tesselation of a geographical area, but I must use my own metric, as the voronoi will take the baricenters from another function and the metrics must be the same. Scipy spatial doesnt allow this, and looking in qhull could not find an option to specify the metric, Is there any other library which may allow me to do this?